# Connect to Vertica from Datagrip

Tags: sql, odbc, vertica, datagrip

I'm using DataGrip and I'm kind of new in it. There is a case for me to connect to Vertica DB. As far as I know, there is no native provided driver for connection to that type of databases. What steps should I take to connect to it? Is there some driver to deal with?

Thanks!

Comment: DataGrip provided solution like this case:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#vertica_as_unsupported_dbms

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to add the Vertica jdbc jar as a driver. Download it from the Vertica site, then:

1. Go to File / Data Sources
2. Right click somewhere and click Add / Driver
3. Give it a name
4. Select the jdbc jar file you downloaded
5. Set the class to `com.vertica.jdbc.Driver`
6. Dialect: `PostgreSQL`

As for how well this works, I'm not sure. It really depends on how DataGrip uses jdbc. But this is how you would add it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @woot answer

I would add that when you setup the datasource connection to `Vertica`. Set the URL with below format.

> URL: jdbc:vertica://{HOST}:{PORT}/{DB}